# JPA/EclipseLink Inherited subtypes in collection operations?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Inherited subtypes seem to break collection queries, this:

```
SELECT o FROM Job AS o WHERE o.occupation = :occupation AND o NOT IN :jobs
```

dies with the dread

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of Campaign use setObject ...
```

when the :jobs collection contains a Campaign, a subclass of Job.

Is this as expected or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.  The issue is that you are passing in a collection of entities when JPA only supports a collection of values.  Try using
  "SELECT o FROM Job AS o WHERE o.occupation = :occupation AND o.id NOT IN :jobs_id"

where jobs_id is a collection of the primary key values.

Comment: Interesting, the EclipseLink docs say it's ok [https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/jpql#Additions_to_Collection_Member_Expressions] and other than this case where the collection contains multiple types it works well.

Comment: The EclipseLink doc only shows a field comparison example ( e.id in :param), and the JPA 2.0 spec section 4.6.9 states: "The state_field_path_expression must have a string, numeric, date, time, timestamp, or enum value.".  It does not allow entity comparisons, as it would not work for all entity or mapping types on all databases.  I'm not sure which version of EclipseLink you are using - it may work on a later one, but as it is unsupported by the spec and won't work for all types, you are better off fixing your query.